# ID apache-service-running in SLS apache.service.running is not a dictionary

Tags: admin, salt-stack

I'm trying to install and configure apache using the v1.2.2 [saltstack apache-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula)

```
salt server-test state.apply apache test=true
```

But keep getting the following error:

```
server-test:
Data failed to compile:
```

---

```
ID apache-service-running in SLS apache.service.running is not a dictionary
```

my master salt path looks like that:

> ```
> file_roots:
>   base:
>     - /srv/salt/states
>     - /srv/salt/formulas/php
>     - /srv/salt/formulas/nginx
>     - /srv/salt/formulas/apache-formula
>     - /srv/salt/formulas/mysql-formula
>     - /srv/salt/files
>
> pillar_roots:
>   base:
>     - /srv/salt/pillar/base
>   dev:
>     - /srv/salt/pillar/dev
>   prod:
>     - /srv/salt/pillar/prod
> ```

I can't figure out where the problem is! any hints?

pillar/base/apache/server-test.sls

```
apache:
  manage_service_states: False
  lookup:
    version: '2.4'
    # for each site name there must be a config in salt://configs/webserver/apache2/sites/
    site_names: [ 'server-test' ]
  security:
    ServerTokens: Prod
  modules:
    enabled:
      - ssl
      - alias
      - rewrite
      - headers
      - shib
      - http2
   #disabled:
   #  - php7.3
   # others are managed elsewhere
   # - status
   #      - proxy
   #- proxy_fcgi
  mpm:
    module: mpm_event
    params:
      start_servers: 3
      min_spare_threads: 50
      max_spare_threads: 100
      thread_limit: 64
      threads_per_child: 25
      max_request_workers: 2000
      server_limit: 80
      max_connections_per_child: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is broken: [#383](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula/issues/383)

`manage_service_states: False` doesn't work.